# jQuery .click taking precedence over .hover

Tags: jquery, printing, window, click, hover

I have a print icon (image) which, when clicked, calls `window.print();`.  However, I also have a hover event for this same print icon, which changes the image src (gradient effect).

The code:

```
   $( "#print_icon" ).hover(

    //mouseover
    function(){
        $( this ).attr( "src", "http://example.com/images/image1.png" );
    },

    //mouseout
    function(){
        $( this ).attr( "src", "http://example.com/images/image2.png" );
    });

// print onclick//
$( "#print_icon" ).click(function() {
    window.print();
});
```

The problem:

Without clicking, the hover works as intended.  When someone clicks the image, the print window appears, but the "mouseout" function doesn't run until the print window is dismissed.  I'd like to change this behavior, so that the mouseout function will run even if the print window is active, or displayed.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

still doesn't work as intended:

```
$( "#print_icon" ).hover(

    //mouseover
    function(){
        $( this ).attr( "src", "http://library.weill.cornell.edu/prc/images/print_icon_onclick.png" );
        $( this ).click(function() {
            window.print();
        });
    },

    //mouseout
    function(){
        $( this ).attr( "src", "http://library.weill.cornell.edu/prc/images/print_icon.png" );
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the click event to the $(this) inside the first hover funct? Might not work...

Comment: This did not work, and it also called the print window numerous times.  I'm not sure if I wrote exactly what you had in mind (see code under "Update").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all browsers I know of, window.print() launches a modal print window -- that is, a window that prevents all other interaction with the web page until it is closed. This is by design -- the browser is grabbing a snapshot of the web page as it was rendered when the print operation began.

In short, there is no way to trigger mouseout events while the print window is open.

The best alternative would be to trigger the mouseleave event in your click handler before starting the print operation:

```
// Click Handler
$( "#print_icon" ).click(function() {
  $(this).mouseleave();
  window.print();
});
```

You will most likely move your mouse off the button anyway to select your printer settings, so for practical purposes, this will fix the problem.

**Update**

setTimeout() *can* modify the page while the modal window is open -- at least in Firefox 5. Try this:

```
// Click Handler
$( "#print_icon" ).click(function() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout( function() {
    $(that).mouseleave();
  }, 2000);
  window.print();
});
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but after clicking the print icon, the image src changes even though the cursor is still hovering over the image

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer. Short version: there's no way to directly do what you're asking. This is the closest substitute as I see it.

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct in virtue of its thorough explanation and practicality.  Before we put this to rest, would there be any way to set a delay on mouseleave, as in a 2 second delay, for example?

Comment: The "mouseout" effect doesn't take place until the print window is dismissed.  I'm pretty satisfied with the way it is now, so unless you wish to fidget further for your amusement (and then tell me), I'm considering this sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering the "mouseout" event when the "click" event is executed. This way you force your printer image to change.

```
// Click Handler
$( "#print_icon" ).click(function() {
  $(this).trigger('mouseout');
  window.print();
});
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but after clicking the print icon, the image src changes even though the cursor is still hovering over the image

Comment: This happens because you're forcing the "mouseout" event to happen. Besides as @kingjiv says: "The print dialog blocks all interaction with the page, therefore your events will never fire while it is open."

Comment: You can also make that happen without javascript. You should also try using CSS to do that e.g.  #print_icon:hover{background: url(image/url);} So when a user's mouse is over/out the button, the image will change.

Comment: As my code stands now, this does not work because I'm trying to give an image (print icon) a background-image.  I really can't think of any other way either to use CSS hover to accomplish the intended effect, and since I have the two print images already, I think I'll go with Josh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing you can do about this.  The print dialog blocks all interaction with the page, therefore your events will never fire while it is open.